# cv2 contourArea returned value

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I went through the opencv-python documentation for the method cv2.contourArea() in order to understand the context of the returned value. But i need some clarification. For instance, if the area of a contour is 32.0, how does it translate to the number of pixels in the image (width or height)?

How is the area returned related to the pixels of the image?Is there a formula?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific and detailed? The question seems too broad.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I meant to ask the metrics of the returned value from cv2.contourArea(). How does it relate to the unit "pixels" in the image.

Comment: ah that's a good question. As far as I know it uses green theorem for calculating the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) uses the green formula to calculate the area of contour.

[This link](https://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area#:%7E:text=We%20can%20parametrized%20it%20in,dt%3D%CF%80r2.) explains How the green formula is used to calculate area  with examples

[Nykamp DQ, “Using Green's theorem to find area.” From Math Insight.](http://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area)